# Prove that every planar triangular graph on 7 vertices has la vertex of vertex degree at least 5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that every triangular planar graph (each face is of size 3) on 7 vertices has at least one vertex of degree 5.

I tried using the corollary of Euler's formula:

$$\sum_{v\epsilon V }^{}[d(v) -6]+ \sum_{\alpha \epsilon  F}^{}[2d(\alpha) - 6] = -12$$

since $d(\alpha) = 3$ for every $\alpha$, the second sum will be equal to: $$\sum_{\alpha \epsilon F}^{}(6-6) = 0$$

$$\sum_{v\epsilon V }^{}[d(v) -6] = -12$$

We can split the first sum into two sums. The second sum will subtract $-6$ for every vertex.

$$[\sum_{v\epsilon V }^{}d(v)] -42= -12$$

$$\sum_{v\epsilon V }^{}d(v) = 30$$

We get a similar result when using the fact that for every planar graph $3n-6>= e$

Thus $ e <= 15$ and according to handshake lemma

$$\sum_{v\epsilon V }^{}d(v)= 2m = 2*15 = 30$$

So if the maximum degree was $4$ than adding it up for all 7 vertices wouldn't give us 30. Thus there must be a vertex of degree at least $6$. I'm supposed to prove it for vertex degree of at least $5$ but that still wouldn't add up to 30.

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: Your use of parentheses is highly unconventional – none of the parentheses you used are needed, and all the ones that are needed are missing. I take it you mean e.g. $\sum_{\alpha\in F}(6-6)=0$?

Comment: Why is it $-6$ in the first equation but $-4$ in the third – is that a typo? And (generally, but especially since this is currently hard to read) it would make sense to state the corollary that you're using.

Comment: @joriki, yes, sorry. I'll fix it.

Comment: @joriki, the corollary I've used is in the second paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I misunderstood the definition of triangular, planar graph, but here is what I think is an counterexample:

[image: Example graph]

a, b have degree 6, "1" and "5" have degree 3 and "2","3","4" have degree 4. Maybe the exercise should have been to proof that there is a node of at least degree 5, which you have already proven.

Comment: It's a graph where evry face has size 3. In your example, ab5a bounds a face of size 4. So this isn't a triangular graph.

Comment: I see no face ab5a, only a5b and ab1(?)

Comment: @runtotherescue Looks triangular to me. Face 'ab5a' has $3$ edges.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. You're right. Well, then how do I prove the statement above then? @Dodezv

Comment: @runtotherescue You yourself wrote: "So if the maximum degree was 4 than adding it up for all 7 vertices wouldn't give us 30." The logical conclusion: There must be a vertex with degree at least 5. I don't know why you have 6 in your next sentence.

Comment: @Dodezv, because if we assume that there is one vertex degree equal to 5 and the remaining six vertices have degree 4, then it would add up to only to 29, wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually no. There have to be two vertices of degree 5, don't they? According to the corollary of the handshake lemma, the amount of odd degrees has to be even. So there cant be only one odd degree!

Comment: No, much simpler: If the max degree were 4 or lower, the sum would be at most 28. This is a contradiction, so the max degree is at least 5. This literally means there is a vertex with degree at least 5.